# Proof of non-convergence of sine series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series

**2** By considering the identity $\cos[(2n-1)\alpha]-\cos[(2n+1)\alpha]\equiv2\sin\alpha\sin2n\alpha,$ show that if $\alpha$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$ then $\sum_{n=1}^N \sin (2n\alpha) = \tfrac12 \cot\alpha -\tfrac12 \operatorname{cosec}\alpha\cos[(2N+1)\alpha]. \tag{4}$   Deduce that the infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin (\tfrac23n\pi) \tag1$ does not converge.

Hello. I bring into your consideration the following question on series. The first part of the question is relatively straightforward, using the method of differences on the left side we then divide by the constant term $2\sin\alpha$ to obtain what is required in the first part. However, I am completely nonplussed as to what train of thought/logic has to be followed for the second part. Any input or clarification will be much appreciated. Do keep in mind though that this question holds only the weight of a single mark so will probably not require exhaustive calculation/elaborate proof.

Comment: The easy answer is that $\frac13$ is not an integer.  You could alternatively show that the partial sums take three different values

Comment: @CarstenS I hope it is better now.

Comment: Try setting $\alpha = 1/3$ in the identity and then evaluating the expression for $N=1,2,3,\dots$ and see if you observe a pattern.

Comment: @Henry I got how you compared α to one-third of pi, but could you please elaborate a bit on exactly what significance integer multiples of pi are bringing here? Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @podiki OK so I observe that the first term in the first derived result will stay constant; but what happens when the cos tends towards infinity? I apologize profusely for my inadequacy of knowledge; because the context and examination for which this question is set does not require *explicit, in-depth knowledge of such mixing of series and trig and is purely an attempt to single out the best-performing candidates.

Comment: If $\alpha $ is an integer multiple of $\pi $ every term of the series is $0$. Can you draw from this a conclusion about the convergence of the series?

Comment: @user Thank you! I get it.

Comment: In fact it holds for integer multiplies of $\pi/2$.